# Pertaining to dead links in accepted answers

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, broken-link

I recently found an accepted answer which was the only answer to a question and had a dead link. How do I deal with that? Should I down vote because the answer only had a link in it as a significant source? Does stackoverflow crawl and point out dead links in accepted answers?

The question is [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503690/net-enabling-start-tag-requires-shorttag-yes/9504148)

Comment: Could you please put a link to this example in your question.

Comment: Downvote, comment, flag (if it's link-only)

Comment: For a feature-request, you should explicitly say what the feature is you are proposing. Also, you should provide a strong argument as to *why* it would be helpful to the comminuty.

Comment: It's not advised for users to post a link only answer or even link-mostly answer, where the (or most of) actual answer data is on an external site. As such, downvote, flag, comment - all or some, whichever you feel is appropriate to the scenario (cannot tell as you didn't provide a link). Some relevant info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115246 ( which

Comment: I can still access the link, though? Are you referring to the dead links in the external article (links to lads.msdn....).

Comment: @nhahtdh I swear it was down yesterday :D but well I didn't downvote or anything , just commented so it's all okay